# Can my institute watch what I'm doing with my school email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, privacy

Recently, I joined to a certificate course in Software Engineering in a reputed private institute in my country. They gave me an `outlook` email address but ends with `@institute_name.com`. They said that I can use it to sign up free to `Office 365` and I can have 1TB of `OneDrive` space. Moreover I can download some software like `Visual Studio` for free using that student email.

- Can they monitor what I'm doing in `Office 365` which I signed in with this account?
- Can they see what I stored in `OneDrive`?
- Can they see my emails?
- I found that I can use that email as a 'student email' to get access to some educational materials in various sites. If I use that email, will my institute get to know about it?
- What are the other possible privacy concerns I should care about, if I use apps or online accounts associated with that email, to my personal use rather than academic works?

Comment: They can monitor anything that is not encrypted during transport over their network.

Comment: School email? Yes they have full access to your emails, even if you delete them.

Comment: Golden rule: Don't mix business with pleasure. Retain two separate identities for two separate purposes.

Comment: @Moab I signed in to my personal PC at home with that email (mainly to get Office 365 free :) ) via my home Wi-Fi connection. Does it make any difference?

Comment: They cannot monitor home use, all they can see is your email.

Comment: @Moab Does that mean whatever I do with Office 365 and save in OneDrive cannot be seen by them, and only thing they can see is the emails I sent to others?

Comment: @AlphaBeta - Office 365 is only offered as a subscription.  If they offer you a discount on a private subscription then the institution cannot read your emails, if you are logging into an email account they have provided then they technically have the capability.  So if the subscription is provided only due to the fact you have logged into `alpha@institute_name.com` then you have been provided an email account provided by the institution and they technically have the capability to read any emails the account receives. This includes any files stored within OneDrive associated with that account.

Comment: Maybe knowing more about Microsoft 365 admin center can help you understand what administrator can exactly do. Please check: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/admin-overview/about-the-admin-center?view=o365-worldwide

Answer (score 4):

They can see and store your email, if unencrypted, since it passes through
their email server.

They can't see what you do with the software you download onto your computer.

They will however see any acknowledgement sent when you use that email to
download software, so will know that you downloaded it.

For OneDrive, use your own account rather than that of the school, to be sure,
because the school administrator is the one that controls the permissions
of the school's OneDrive.

Comment: Are they able to see the content in OneDrive?

Comment: No, they need your password for this. However they can ask for password reset and intercept the return email. This is an illegal hack. But you aren't forced to use their email for OneDrive.

Comment: @harrymc - I don't agree with you statement that an Administrator would be unable to access the contents contained within the author's account assigned to them by their institution. If an administrator is able to view the email the author's email address receives then they have the ability to view the files uploaded to OneDrive.  This is explicitly limited to the Office 365 environment, controlled by the institution, and configured and managed by an Administrator of the institution itself.  **This does not include the proper Office 365 individually subscribed by a user created account.**

Comment: @Ramhound: Once Office 365 is installed on his computer, they cannot access contents stored on his computer. For OneDrive they need the password, which is never passed by email (unless for a temporary password for password reset).

Comment: @harrymc - OneDrive is cloud storage connected to Office 365.  The Microsoft hosted version of OneDrive cannot be accessed by Microsoft employees.  However, Office 365 (commercial) instances of are managed by the institution itself not Microsoft.  The same rules that apply to OneDrive (proper) does not apply to commercial instances of Office 365.  OneDrive (proper) is connected to your Microsoft Account and the amount of storage is provided to that account is determined by your Office 365 and/or additional storage plans.

Comment: @Ramhound: Hard to believe that Microsoft will allow this lack of privacy. Do you have a link for that?

Comment: @harrymc - Microsoft sells managed instances of Office 365 for an enterprise or education institution.  You don't believe that an enterprise instance of Office 365 might have different rules in those cases?  I don't have a link, you will just have to take my word, based on my personal experiences. The solution to the author's problem is to subscribe using their own Microsoft Account instead of using their account provided by their education institution.

Comment: @harrymc I have to agree with Ramhound here. As Office365 admin of multiple tenants, I can  accesse files from OneDrive for any account in a tenant by altering a few permissions, or through PowerShell. The reason this is allowed, is for backup and restore functions.

Comment: @LPChip: This sounds reasonable, although a bit horrifying. I added this advice to my answer.

Comment: Detailed reply. Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: @harrymc In a managed enterprise Microsoft 365 environment, which this clearly is, OneDrive is essentially an enterprise cloud file server and the administrators definitely DO have the ability to view the contents. On a private OneDrive license, only the person who created the instance can see the files, but this isn't a private license: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onedrivefb-mso_other-mso_o365b/can-i-as-365-admin-have-access-to-our-staff-files/4dc72af3-f33f-4f3e-9bcf-3f725a2c0793?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

If the email's domain belongs to the school, they have control of it and can view and monitor your emails. So yes, your institute can monitor emails sent and received with your designated email address.

Comment: I agree with you. But, even though they use their own domain name, the email and other services are provided by Microsoft. And I guess there is some kind of procedure which Microsoft give that type of services to other institutes. Do anyone know what that procedure is?

Comment: @AlphaBeta - The administrator(s) of the overall institution would have access to each and every user account associated with the institution's account.